# Creating app.tss in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can I create app.tss in Titanium? I'm following this link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/10/4-ways-build-mobile-application-part4-appcelerator-titanium/

I think that app.tss is not an alloy controller so I can't just right click on the app in Project Explorer and create an alloy contoller.

Should I just right click and create a new file and label it app.tss. Would that have a negative effect on entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I think that app.tss is not an alloy controller so I can't just right click on the app in Project Explorer and create an alloy contoller.
```

Yes, you are right it is not an Alloy Controller. Files with an extension `TSS` are Titanium Style Sheets. `app.tss` contains styles accessible globally and it is in a folder called `app/styles`. You should have it in your project by default.

If you don't then just do right click on the folder `styles` -> New -> Alloy Style